# System Glitch, Ubuntu, 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a glitch in my build of Ubuntu 18.04.
Several things occur and I'd appreciate help from any who may have similar experience.

am unable to share printer (Brother hll2320d) on network

I am unable to install some apps even tho shown as ''done'' IE:
sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package hll2320dlpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

I am unable to launch installed apps such as gparted.
This app doesn't show as installed even after multiple installs:
dpkg -l gparted
dpkg-query: no packages found matching gparted

Often, a random warning will appear:  ''Warning; there is a problem in the system...'' or similar wording.

I am unable to upgrade to 20.04
"unable to get list of updates: failed to get updates for refresh: E: The package hll2320dlpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

the hll2320 brother printer definitely has a problem with linux but the problem upgrading to 20.04 was a preexisting condition.

Was hoping the upgrade would fix the glitches....

Comment: I doubt you can upgrade a custom build of Ubuntu, also, upgrades usually do not fix things.

Comment: I may be using the wrong terminology;   I would like to update/upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: One question per post please. Pick one of your issues that you'd like addressed and edit the other ones out of the post. You can ask follow-on questions later.

Comment: I have programs on the present system I'd like to save,

Comment: There are few specific details; error messages should be *verbatim* for us to understand & search for them, not "*or similar wording*". You didn't say if server, or desktop, but given you provide a 32-bit (:386) reference in your post; Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the last i386/32-bit x86 supported release; so you cannot upgrade a i386 system to 20.04 (it could go to 18.10 & 19.04 but no further). Package `hll2320dlpr` doesn't exist in Ubuntu repositories so if it was added to your system, it was 3rd party

Answer (score 1):

You said that you are getting output: `E: The package hll2320dlpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Apt is stuck by this problem. It cannot do *anything else* until you provide the original .deb package again. It can't install new software. It can't delete old software. It cannot upgrade or apply security patches.

**The easiest, fastest solution** is to download the package again from the Brother website. Then put the downloaded deb in your /var/cache/apt/archives, and let apt re-install it (`sudo apt install --reinstall hll2320dlpr`)

**The messy, slow solution** is to use dpkg's `--force-remove-reinstreq` flag (I call it the nuclear option) to make apt and dpkg forget that they installed the package. However, this will leave whatever files that package installed still littering your filesystem; you must clean that radioactive debris manually. If you fail to do so completely, you will encounter other dpkg errors that continue to prevent apt from making progress. **Warning:** This site is soaked in the tears of folks who used this dangerous option injudiciously -- and broke their systems.

Comment: The pkg is the printer driver.  Brother doesn't support Linux and this is a USB printer - unusable on a network.  I thot I could work around this by using a USB switch, as others have evidently done this successfully with usb printers, so I downloaded the driver to Ubuntu thinking to simply switch back and forth btwn computers.   If I download another instance of this driver and put it in var/cache/apt/archives will this leave behind an artifact of the old pkg to contaminate the system?

Comment: The whole point of using apt is to prevent "artifacts" of that sort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This may solve a problem I've been banging my head on for some time.  Prolly won't be able to figger out how to use the printer on linux but this fixes a bigger problem.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Tried to install new instance of hll2320d driver fm Brother site:   Error msg;  "Sorry, something went wrong.  failed to get details for hll2320dlpr;3.2.0-1;i386;local: E: The package hll2320dlpr;I386 needs to be reinstalled but I can't find an archive for it."  I am unable to get beyond this message to install, reinstall or remove.  BTW, I have a Brother installer in my home directory. not sure if this is important, just info.

Comment: I found 4 instances ov .deb files, 2 werehll2320dcupswrappers, and 2 were hll2320dlpr in /Downloads.  I moved (via terminal) all 4 to /var/cache/apt/archives successfully but when run sudo apt install --reinstall hll2320dlpr (and cupswrapper) I get the following error:         "E: The package hll2320dlpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."  Stumped!